# XNA - How to draw lines in world space?

Tags: 3d, xna, lines, perspective

I'm working on an A* algorithm, and I'd like to be able to draw lines between the nodes in the path-finding graph, especially those leading to the exit. The environment I'm working in is 3D. I just couldn't figure out why my code wasn't displaying the lines, so I simplified it so that It'd render just one line. Now I can see a line, but its in screen space, instead of world space. Is there an easy way to draw lines in world coordinates in XNA?

Here's the code:

```
        _lineVtxList = new VertexPositionColor[2];
        _lineListIndices = new short[2];

        _lineListIndices[0] = 0;
        _lineListIndices[1] = 1;
        _lineVtxList[0] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Color.MediumPurple);
        _lineVtxList[1] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(100, 0, 0), Color.MediumPurple);
        numLines = 1;
....
            BasicEffect basicEffect = new BasicEffect(g);
            basicEffect.VertexColorEnabled = true;
            basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
            basicEffect.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
            basicEffect.Projection = projMat;
            basicEffect.View = viewMat;
            if (_lineListIndices != null && _lineVtxList != null)
            {

            //    g.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(PrimitiveType.LineList, _lineVtxList, 0, 1);

                g.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(
                        PrimitiveType.LineList,
                        _lineVtxList,
                        0,  // vertex buffer offset to add to each element of the index buffer
                        _lineVtxList.Length,  // number of vertices in pointList
                        _lineListIndices,  // the index buffer
                        0,          // first index element to read
                        numLines   // number of primitives to draw
                        );
            }
```

The matrices projMat and viewMat are the same view and projection matrices I use to render 
everything else in the scene. It doesn't seem to matter whether I assign them to basicEffect or not. Here's what the scene looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't beginning or ending your `BasicEffect` so the projection and view matricies won't be applied to `DrawUserIndexedPrimitives`.  Try encompasing your `DrawUserIndexedPrimitives` call with this:

```
if (_lineListIndices != null && _lineVtxList != null)
{
    basicEffect.Begin();
    foreach (EffectPass pass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passses)
    {
        pass.Begin();
        g.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(...); // The way you have it
        pass.End();
    }
    basicEffect.End();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I'm using XNA 4.0, this version of BasicEffect doesn't have that method.

Comment: turns out that Begin() and End() aren't part of BasicEffect anymore, instead you just type: pass.apply(), and don't worry about ending anything. Thanks for your response though, that set me on the right track! I edited your response to reflect v4.0, so my previous comment can be ignored.

Comment: Looks like you edited it back. This might be effective in XNA 3.0, but not in 4.0. In 4.0, you just call pass.Begin(), but you don't need basicEffect.Begin(), or basicEffect.End()

Comment: @NickLokarno Odd... I haven't touched your edit.  It's possible your edit wasn't approved via the review process, otherwise it would have an "Edited by" mark.  Seems strange :/